# Why does this code only writes the first and the last occurrences of nome, cognome and cf?

Tags: c

Why does this code only writes the first and the last occurrences of nome, cognome and cf?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct data{
    char nome[20];
    char cognome[20];
    char cf[20];
    }data;

void leggi_file(FILE *input, data **array, int *dim);
void aggiorna(data *vect, char *nome, char *cognome, char *cf, int dim);
void scrivi_file(FILE *output, data *vect, int dim);


int main(void){
    FILE *input, *output; 
    input = fopen("prog1file.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("prog1file2.txt", "w");
    data *vect1;
    int dim_vect1 = 0;

    leggi_file(input,&vect1,&dim_vect1);

    char *nome="Michele", *cognome="Nappi", *cf="nppmhl69p22b119f";
    aggiorna(vect1, nome, cognome, cf, dim_vect1);

    scrivi_file(output, vect1, dim_vect1);

    return 0;
}   

void leggi_file(FILE *input, data **array, int *dim){
    char nome[20], cognome[20], cf[17];
    int i;
    while(fscanf(input, "%s %s %s", nome, cognome, cf) == 3)
        (*dim)++;
    *array = malloc((*dim + 1) * sizeof(data));
    rewind(input);
    for(i=0; i<(*dim); i++)
        fscanf(input, "%s %s %s", array[i]->nome, array[i]->cognome, array[i]->cf);
}

void aggiorna(data *vect, char *nome, char *cognome, char *cf, int dim){
    strcpy(vect[dim].nome, nome);
    strcpy(vect[dim].cognome, cognome);
    strcpy(vect[dim].cf, cf);
}

void scrivi_file(FILE *output, data *vect, int dim){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<(dim+1); i++)
        fprintf(output, "%s %s %s\n", vect[i].nome, vect[i].cognome, vect[i].cf);
}
```

It should write the occurrences of nome, cognome and cf that are stored in the first file in the second, and then add another one which was passed from the main. Why does it only write the first and the last?

In the output file I get something like this:

```
Giuseppe Nappo nppgspmhl65t23c126a


Michele Nappi nppmhl69p22b119f
```

Comment: This might be a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: In function `leggi_file()` you have allocated an array of pointers with `*array = malloc((*dim + 1) * sizeof(data));` but not initialised the pointers themselves.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think I initialized it in the main

Comment: @WeatherVane This is an array of structs not pointers.  I think the malloc is OK. (My C foo is a little out of condition these days so I could easily have missed something)

Comment: I was reading it as though `sizeof(data)` is the size of the pointer, but it isn't.

Comment: So, by first and last you mean the first entry in the file and the "Michele Nappi" entry you provide yourself?  If so then I thing the problem is that "leggi_file" function is only reading the first line.  You need to put some debug in tere.  It may be the fscanf is not dealy with newline characters (for example).

Comment: @EuanSmith even if the strings are on the same line it still writes only the first and the last occurrences

Comment: @user10994677 have you added some debug to find out if the problem is in the reading or writing?  You need to narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: OT: regarding: `input = fopen("prog1file.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("prog1file2.txt", "w");`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "your error message" ); then `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  The `perror()` will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: OT: always enable the warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.  The compiler will output: "untitled2.c:38:32: warning: conversion to ‘long unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]"  Such problems should be corrected

Comment: OT: why is the struct field `cy` defined as 20 bytes but the local variable `cy` in function: `leggi_file()` defining the field as only 17 bytes?

Comment: @user3629249 I fixed it. I still doesn't work.

Comment: OT: regarding: `while(fscanf(input, "%s %s %s", nome, cognome, cf) == 3)` when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[..]' always specify a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: OT: regarding: `fscanf(input, "%s %s %s", array[i]->nome, array[i]->cognome, array[i]->cf);`  this is missing the check (==3) that assures the operation was successful

Answer (score 3):

In the `leggi_file` function, `array` is a pointer to a pointer of structures. Think of it as a pointer to an array of structures. It is most definitely not an array of pointers to structures (as the use `array[i]->nome` would indicate).

The correct way is to dereference the pointer to get the array (of ***structures***), as in `(*array)[i].nome`.

With `array[i]->nome` you treat `array` as an array of pointers, which it is not. It's (effectively, but not semantically) a pointer to an array.

By using `array[i]->nome` you will go out of bounds of the memory for `array`, leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You're lucky (or unlucky depending on point of view) that the code don't crash.

The only line you need to change is this one:

```
fscanf(input, "%s %s %s", array[i]->nome, array[i]->cognome, array[i]->cf);
```

Which you should change into

```
fscanf(input, "%s %s %s", (*array)[i].nome, (*array)[i].cognome, (*array)[i].cf);
```

Comment: By the way, array[i]->nome is the same as (*array)[i].nome so I don't see how that is an error

Comment: @user10994677 That's the problem because those two are ***not*** equal. `array` is not an array of pointers. It's a pointer to an array (effectively but not semantically).

Comment: @user10994677 And `*array = malloc(...)` is correct.

Comment: @user10994677 `array[i]->nome` is equivalent to `(*(array[i])).nome`, not `(*array)[i].nome` - there's an important distinction !

Comment: @SanderDeDycker as you can see in my code I wrote array[i]->nome

Comment: Using your solution it still writes only the first and the last ones

Comment: @user10994677 With the small change indicted by my answer (and to read from `stdin` and write to `stdout` instead), [it seems to work fine](https://ideone.com/Bq849Q).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I had written (*array[i]).nome instead of (*array)[i].nome. Now it works, thank you very much!